# Navigation menu disappearing

Tags: html, css, css-float

Update: Still a beginner question - the navigation now appears but is not inline. I have a jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/4zzkV/

Beginner question. The  #navigation menu that is not appearing. If I comment out the #navigation in CSS it does appear, but not inline.

Html :

```
        <div id="page">
         <div id="content">
              <div id="header">
                  <div id="menu" >
                     <h1>Title</h1
                  </div>
                  <ul id="navigation">
                      <li id="contact_us"><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                      <li id="about_us"><a href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
                      <li id="index"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
               <div id="middle">

                   <div id="main_image">
                        <img src="images/eiffel_900_500.png" alt="Paris and Brooklyn">
                   </div>

              </div>
              <div id="footer">
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
 #content{
   width: 900px;
   height: 200px;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
 }

 #header{

    margin: 0;
    background-image: url(../images/header2.png);
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
     float:left;
 }

 #menu {}

 #navigation {float:right; display:inline;}
```

Comment: Could you post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? By the way, you missed a `>` for closing your h1 tag.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I missed the closing > for the h1. Now I have a different problem. I'm working on Fiddle now.

Comment: The jsFiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/4zzkV/ The problems is that the navigation is now not inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do but if you want the links to display on the same line from the right side and under the title, you'll need to add the following to the CSS

```
#navigation li { display: inline;}
```

Alternatively you could add this:

```
#navigation li {float: right; margin-left: 10px}
```

You want to tell each of the links to float or display inline, not the main div.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be almost it but they don't seem to be displaying on the same line as the title.

Comment: Are you trying to have each of the links right after the title or just floated to the right but on the same line as the title?

If you want it floated to the right, but on the same line as the title add position:absolute; to the h1 CSS

Comment: I tried position:absolute on h1, but got some strange results. JsFiddle dropped the title below the other elements.

Comment: gotta set you height as well. for the div so the middle falls below

Answer (score 0):

The navigation items aren't inline because you haven't set them inline. Try setting

```
#navigation li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/4zzkV/8/embedded/result/

Comment: Thanks, as I noted to Matto, now they don't seem to be on the same line as the title or am I just not seeing that correctly?

Comment: You need to set a width explicitly on these floated elements. #header 1 { width: 45%; float: left; } #navigation { float:right; width: 50%; } (adjust to your liking)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your problem is solved or not, but I guess here's what you need
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anirudhvarma/8xd6a/)

I added the `line-height` method, if that's ok with you.

UPDATE: If you see the fiddle, there's another method that works without explicitly setting height of header